# Wobbly windows not working in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: windows, compiz, configuration, configure, configuration-management

I have enabled the wobbly windows option in compizConfig settings manager and also disabled Snapping windows still wobbly windows not working in my ubuntu 22.04 please help
[image: img]
[image: img2]

Comment: Try to move to XServer Session, wayland will not work (log out, selected the litte cog icon and select XServer)

Comment: Also, try the GNOME extension instead of Compiz https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/06/how-to-enable-wobbly-windows-effect-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts